# Is the following usage of "alone" correct?

Tags: word-usage

A friend of mine came to me while I was drinking tea with another person. So two of us were drinking tea and a third person approaching us.
The third person said: "*You people came alone*". His point was that we didn't call him for tea.

My question is, can two people *come alone*? Is it not a wrong usage of *alone*?

Comment: The usage of "alone" in the question bothers me less than the usage of "below" in the title.

Comment: Please leave my children alone. The passing of the Lion king had left the critters of the land in chaos, each tribe alone to their own devices.

Answer (score 2):

The word alone usually means 'on his / her / its own' or some paraphrase.

However, in

> We are not alone
>
> Couples want to be alone together [internet]

it is clearly acceptable for 'alone' also to be applied to an isolated group.

Stylewise, though, there may well be situations where this usage sounds unnatural.

> ??John, Jill, Tom, Brenda and Fred alone had finished their essays.
>
> Only John, Jill, Tom, Brenda and Fred had finished their essays.

Comment: So, is this `You people came alone` usage justified?

Comment: It's certainly not incorrect, but 'You two came without me' is what I'd expect (I'm in the UK). It might sound more natural to US native speakers.

Comment: As a native speaker of U.S.  English, I have the same reservations about it that you two do. And the situation gets worse as more and more people are added to the gathering that excludes the speaker: "Why did the ten of you decide to come here alone [that is, without including me in your company]?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *alone* can refer to multiple people or things, set apart from others. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alone) gives an example:

> They were not alone in dissenting from the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the word *alone* can refer to either one person or a group of multiple people. Some examples include:

*We want to be alone.* ("we" refers to multiple people)

*I sat on the empty, dark-lit street - all alone - just me, the street and the rain.* ("I" & "Just me" refers to one person)